# ValueError: arange: cannot compute length

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using a script on python "format_snow_param.py". This script takes geotiff data for snow band parameterization and converts it to the needed text format for the VIC model

```
Usage: python format_snow_params.py <template raster> <elevation raster>
<output snow band file> <interval for snow bands>
```

on the terminal I type the following command:

```
Format elevation band file: $ python format_snow_params.py
../data/input/gis/Nyando_grid.tif
../data/input/gis/Nyando_basin_SRTMSnap.tif ../data/input/snow.param 100
```

The results give this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "format_snow_params.py",
> line 203, in <module>
>     main()     File "format_snow_params.py", line 197, in main
>     format_snow_params(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4])  
> File "format_snow_params.py", line 112, in format_snow_params
>     bands = np.arange(minelv, maxelv+interval, interval) ValueError: arange: cannot compute length
```

---

Here is the modification of my question, following the comments.
I used Luke's script, in which he added the print, and the output results is the following:

```
Min: --
Max: --
Int: 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format_snow_params1.py", line 194, in <module>
    main() 
  File "format_snow_params1.py", line 188, in main
    format_snow_params(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4])
  File "format_snow_params1.py", line 100, in format_snow_params
    bands = np.arange(minelv, maxelv+interval, interval)
ValueError: arange: cannot compute length
```

the output results of the command `gdalinfo -stats Nyando_basin_SRTMSnap.tif` :

```
gdalinfo: Relink `/home/lgee/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libpng16.so.16' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0' for IFUNC symbol `longjmp'
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Nyando_basin_SRTMSnap.tif
Size is 3300, 1500
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (34.750000000000000,0.050000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000303030303030,-0.000333333333333)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  34.7500000,   0.0500000) 
Lower Left  (  34.7500000,  -0.4500000) 
Upper Right (  35.7500000,   0.0500000) 
Lower Right (  35.7500000,  -0.4500000) 
Center      (  35.2500000,  -0.2000000) 
Band 1 Block=3300x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1134.000, Maximum=2862.000, Mean=1735.713, StdDev=473.560
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+38
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2862
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1735.7128876922
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1134
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=473.55999424241
```

the output results of the command gdalinfo -stats Nyando_grid.tif :

```
gdalinfo: Relink `/home/lgee/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libpng16.so.16' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0' for IFUNC symbol `longjmp'
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Nyando_grid.tif
Size is 20, 10
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (34.750000000000000,0.050000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.050000000000000,-0.050000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  34.7500000,   0.0500000) 
Lower Left  (  34.7500000,  -0.4500000) 
Upper Right (  35.7500000,   0.0500000) 
Lower Right (  35.7500000,  -0.4500000) 
Center      (  35.2500000,  -0.2000000) 
Band 1 Block=20x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=1.000, Mean=1.000, StdDev=0.000
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
```

attached script:

```
# import dependencies
import os
import sys
import warnings
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalnumeric import *  
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

# set system to ignore simple warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

def format_snow_params(basinMask,elvHiRes,outSnow,interval):
    """
    FUNCTION: format_snow_params
    ARGUMENTS: basinMask - path to template raster to run VIC model at
               elvHiRes - path elevation raster dataset at native resolution
               outsnow - path output snow parameter file
               interval - vertical distance to do equal interval segmentation
    KEYWORDS: n/a
    RETURNS: n/a
    NOTES: Does not return a variable but writes an output file
    """

    band = 1 # constant variable for reading in data

    interval = int(interval) # force equal interval value to be int type

    # make a list of input raster files
    infiles = [basinMask,elvHiRes]

    # try to read in the raster data
    try:

        # read basin grid raster
        ds = gdal.Open(infiles[0],GA_ReadOnly)
        b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
        mask = BandReadAsArray(b1)
        maskRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1]
        ds = None
        b1 = None

        # read hi res elevation raster
        ds = gdal.Open(infiles[1],GA_ReadOnly)
        b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
        elvhires = BandReadAsArray(b1)
        clsRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1] 
        ds = None
        b1 = None

    # if not working, give error message
    except AttributeError:
        raise IOError('Raster file input error, check that all paths are correct')

    # mask elevation values less than 0
    elvhires = np.ma.masked_where(elvhires<0,elvhires)

    # get ratio of high resoltion to low resolution
    clsRatio = int(maskRes/clsRes)

    # check if the output parameter file exists, if so delete it
    if os.path.exists(outSnow)==True:
        os.remove(outSnow)    

    nbands = [] # blank list

    # try to write to output snow parameter file
    try:

        with open(outSnow, 'w') as f:

            cnt = 1 # set grid cell id counter

            # pass counter
            pass_counter = range(2)

            # perform two passes on the raster data
            # 1) to grab the maximum number of bands for a given pixel
            # 2) to calculate the snow band parameters and write to output file
            for pass_cnt in pass_counter:

                # loop over each pixel in the template raster
                for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
                    cy1 = i*clsRatio
                    cy2 = cy1+clsRatio

                    for j in range(mask.shape[1]):     
                        cx1 = j*clsRatio
                        cx2 = cx1+clsRatio

                        # get all hi res pixels in a template pixel
                        tmp = elvhires[cy1:cy2,cx1:cx2]

                        # find min and max values for interval
                        minelv = np.min(tmp.astype(int)) - (np.min(tmp.astype(int))%interval)
                        maxelv = np.max(tmp.astype(int)) + (np.max(tmp.astype(int))%interval)

                        # create an array of band limits  
                        try:
                            bands = np.arange(minelv, maxelv+interval, interval)
                        except:
                            print('Min: %s\nMax: %s\nInt: %s'%(minelv, maxelv, interval))
                            raise

                        # create blank array for number of bands calculation...
                        if mask[i,j] == 1: # ...if it is not a masked pixel

                            bcls = np.zeros_like(tmp)
                            bcls[:,:] = -1

                            # get the number of bands per pixel
                            for b in range(bands.size-1):

                                bcls[np.where((tmp>=bands[b])&(tmp<bands[b+1]))] = b # band counter

                                # if it's the first pass get number of bands for each pixel
                                if pass_cnt == 0:
                                    uniqcnt = np.unique(bcls[np.where(tmp>0)])
                                    nbands.append(uniqcnt.size) # save to a list for second pass

                            if pass_cnt == 1:
                                uniqcnt = np.unique(bcls[np.where(tmp>0)])
                                #clscnt = np.bincount(tmp.ravel())                

                                f.write('{0}\t'.format(cnt)) # write grid cell id

                                # find frational area for each band and write to file
                                for c in range(maxbands):
                                    try:
                                        idx = np.where(bcls==uniqcnt[c])
                                        frac = np.float(idx[0].size) / np.float(bcls[np.where(bcls>=0)].size)
                                    except IndexError:
                                        frac = 0

                                    f.write('{0:.4f}\t'.format(frac))

                                # calculate the mean elevation for each band and write to file
                                for c in range(maxbands):
                                    try:
                                        idx = np.where(bcls==uniqcnt[c])
                                        muelv = np.nanmean(tmp[idx])

                                    except IndexError:
                                        muelv = 0

                                    f.write('{0:.4f}\t'.format(muelv))

                                # calculate the precipitation fractions and write to file
                                for c in range(maxbands):
                                    try:
                                        idx = np.where(bcls==uniqcnt[c])
                                        frac = np.float(idx[0].size) / np.float(bcls[np.where(bcls>=0)].size)
                                    except IndexError:
                                        frac = 0

                                    f.write('{0:.4f}\t'.format(frac))

                                f.write('\n') # write return value for new line

                        if pass_cnt == 1:
                            cnt += 1 # plus one to the grid cell id counter 

                if pass_cnt == 0:
                    maxbands = max(nbands) # maximum number of bands for a pixel  

        # print the number of bands for user to input into global parameter file
        print("Number of maximum bands: {0}".format(maxbands))  

    # except raise an error when it doesn't work                
    except IOError:
        raise IOError('Cannot write output file, error with output snow parameter file path')

    return

def main():
    n_args = len(sys.argv)

    # Check user inputs
    if n_args != 5:
        print("Wrong user input")
        print("Script writes the snow band parameter file for the VIC model")
        print("usage: python format_snow_params.py <template raster> <elevation raster> <output snow band file> <interval for snow bands>")
        print("Exiting system...")
        sys.exit()

    else:
        # Pass command line arguments into function
        format_snow_params(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4])

    return  

# Execute the main level program if run as standalone
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Just as to debug the possible problem, could you add `print(minelv, maxelv, interval, maxelv+interval)` before `bands = np.arange(minelv, maxelv+interval, interval)` and see if they are properly created?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried that but it's still the same problem

Comment: That's to be expected, but what did the last line read (the print statement should have worked before the error occurred).

Comment: Really I have no idea, I don't know much about programming, I just try to execute these codes following a tutorial to work with a land cover modeling VIC model.... :/

Comment: @BouramtaneTarik No one can help you if you can't simply read a line from your computer screen.

Comment: @RJJoling So even adding Print before bands = np.arange(minelv, maxelv+interval, interval), there was always the same error; but I didn't understand what you meant by: but what did the last line read (the print statement should have worked before the error occurred)

Comment: @BouramtaneTarik Adding the "print" statement will output the values of minelv, maxelv, interval, and maxelv+interval so you know what they are. It will do nothing to "fix" your code. It is a diagnostic tool. So you need to tell RJJoling what the values of those variables are.

Comment: Thanks @luke and everyone else,  for your comments I appreciate very much, I just modified the answer following Luke's script

Comment: @Luke here we can see the values of the output results on the modification of the question

Comment: @RJJoling I followed your comment. I hope you find a clue to the issue.

Comment: @Luke done it, here you can see the Output results

Answer (score 1):

Your basin mask has a different pixel size and a different shape (rows and cols) to your elevation grid. From what I can see, the basin mask should be the same size for the code to work.